# Filtering empty rows from Mysql SELECT query issue

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a SELECT query as below:

```
SELECT basket_id
     , b.amount_due - SUM(p.amount_paid) as due_balance
FROM basket_due b
  LEFT JOIN basket_payment p USING (basket_id)
WHERE b.customer_id = 4
GROUP BY customer_id, basket_id
ORDER BY basket_id desc
```

This query gives me an output like this:

```
+-----------+-------------------+
| basket_id |       due_balance |
+-----------+-------------------+
|        16 |            999.50 |
|        15 |              0.00 |
|        13 |              0.00 |
|        11 |           1716.00 |
|         9 |           1210.00 |
|         7 |            140.00 |
+-----------+-------------------+
```

My question is, how to filter the 0 due records from `due_balance` and modify the query to get the rest?

Expecting result should be:

```
+-----------+-------------------+
| basket_id |       due_balance |
+-----------+-------------------+
|        16 |            999.50 |
|        11 |           1716.00 |
|         9 |           1210.00 |
|         7 |            140.00 |
+-----------+-------------------+
```

I tried it in this way, but it doesn't work for me.

```
SELECT basket_id
     , b.amount_due - SUM(p.amount_paid) as due_balance
FROM basket_due b
  LEFT JOIN basket_payment p USING (basket_id)
WHERE b.customer_id = 4 AND due_balance > 0 
GROUP BY customer_id, basket_id
ORDER BY basket_id desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HAVING Clause or use subquery then add condition outside with WHERE clause.

```
SELECT basket_id
     , b.amount_due - SUM(p.amount_paid) as due_balance
FROM basket_due b
  LEFT JOIN basket_payment p USING (basket_id)
WHERE b.customer_id = 4
GROUP BY customer_id, basket_id
Having due_balance > 0 
ORDER BY basket_id desc

SELECT t.basket_id
     , t.due_balance
FROM (SELECT basket_id
           , b.amount_due - SUM(p.amount_paid) as due_balance
      FROM basket_due b
      LEFT JOIN basket_payment p USING (basket_id)
      WHERE b.customer_id = 4
      GROUP BY customer_id, basket_id) t
WHERE t.due_balance > 0
ORDER BY t.basket_id desc
```

Answer (score 1):

The non zero assertion on the due balance belongs in a `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT basket_id,
      b.amount_due - SUM(p.amount_paid) AS due_balance
FROM basket_due b
LEFT JOIN basket_payment p USING (basket_id)
WHERE b.customer_id = 4
GROUP BY customer_id, basket_id
HAVING due_balance > 0
ORDER BY basket_id DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use having

```
SELECT basket_id
     , b.amount_due - SUM(p.amount_paid) as due_balance
FROM basket_due b
  LEFT JOIN basket_payment p USING (basket_id)
WHERE b.customer_id = 4
GROUP BY customer_id, basket_id
Having due_balance > 0 
ORDER BY basket_id desc
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use <> 0. Should be work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).